# Open method for AdoDB.Connection object is not supported in Access 2010

Tags: ms-access, vba, connection, ms-access-2010, adodb

Currently I'm working on an Access Database Application which was using ODBCDirect. After upgrading to Access 2010 I receive an error message that told me that ODBCDirect isn't supported anymore and that I have to change from the DAO to ADO in the corresponding source code parts each time I'm running the application. 
I found out that the origin of this error message was the source code that was responsible for the database connection which was making use of ODBCDirect.

I followed the tutorials about ADODB.Connection objects and the opening of them. I changed this code to the following simple code by using the ADODB.Connection object.

Now I'm receiving the new error message **"(-2147467259) operation is not supported for this type of object"**.

I found out that the place where I was using the Open function of the ADODB.Connection Object is causing the new error message:

```
Global conWork As ADODB.Connection
...
Set conWork = New ADODB.Connection
...
conWork.ConnectionString = "ODBC;DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=someServer.x.y.z;Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;UserID=user;Password=pw;Data Source=someServer.x.y.z; Trusted_Connection=yes;"
...

conWork.Open  //...causes the error msg "OPERATION IS NOT SUPPORTED FOR THIS TYPE OF OBJECT"
```

In the vba editor I have the Microsoft ADO 2.8 Library and the Microsoft ADO 2.8 RecordSet Library selected in the references-settings.

Answer (score 1):

I'm unsure why your attempt fails, but there are several issues which look suspicious to me.

1. Don't include *ODBC;* in your ADO connection string.  Including that piece triggers a run-time error in my tests.
2. I don't believe you should include both *DRIVER={SQL Server}* and *Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0* in your connection string.
3. Including both *UserID=user;Password=pw* and *Trusted_Connection=yes* seems wrong.  Choose one or the other, not both.
4. You must do `Set conWork = New ADODB.Connection` before you set its `ConnectionString` and call `Open`.  I can't tell whether your full code does that; it should.
5. I don't think you need the recordset library reference, but don't know whether including it contributes to the problem.

Maybe you would be better off to start from known-working ADO connection code.  This code works in Access 2010 with the *Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.8 Library* reference and successfully connects to my local SQL Server.

```vb
Dim conWork As ADODB.Connection
Dim strConnect As String
strConnect = "DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=HP64\SQLEXPRESS;Trusted_Connection=Yes;DATABASE=testbed"
Set conWork = New ADODB.Connection
conWork.ConnectionString = strConnect
conWork.Open
```

You can find more information regarding connection strings for SQL Server at [ConnectionStrings.com](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/).

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Unfortunately I forgot to write "Set conWork = New ADODB.Connection" into my question..I updated it now.

Comment: I changed my connectionString to: conWork.ConnectionString = "DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};SERVER=server.x.y.z;Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;UserID=somebody;Password=password;Data Source=server.x.y.z;"    now I am receiving the errormessage "Could not find installable ISAM"

Comment: You're attempting to connect to a database.  Is that database SQL Server or MS Access?  I'm confused.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Now I'm using the connectionString       "Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};Dbq=\\folder1\folder2\User1\Database.mdb; Uid=Admin;Pwd=password;"   . I don't get any connection errors right now,  but have problems with accessing storedProcedures (which are stored on the server) over an ADODB.Command object. I have posted the corresponding question right here -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31540879/the-microsoft-access-database-engine-cannot-find-the-input-table-or-query-dbo