# The microsoft access database engine cannot find the input table or query 'dbo'.. (VBA, Access2010)

Tags: vba, stored-procedures, command, ms-access-2010, adodb

Helllo!
I'm an MS Access-beginner. After an upgrade from Access2003 to Access2010 I am changing the database connection of our MS Access-Application from ODBCDirect (not supported anymore) to ADODB.

After (hopefully) successfully establishing a DB connection over an ADODB.Connection object I am initializing an ADODB.Command object:

```
Dim qdfWork As ADODB.Command
...
Set qdfWork = New ADODB.Command
Set qdfWork.ActiveConnection = CurrentProject.Connection
qdfWork.CommandText = "[dbo].[storedProcedureName]"
qdfWork.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
qdfWork.Parameters.Refresh  'HERE THE ERROR-MESSAGE OCCURS
...
```

There is a stored procedure with the exactly same name "[dbo].[storedProcedureName]" stored on the server, but I still get the error-message:

"the microsoft access database engine cannot find the input table or query 'dbo'. Make sure it exists and that its name is spelled correctly."

If I don't write "[dbo]" in the CommandText I still get the same message, telling that "[storedProcedureName]" can't be found.

Here is my ADODB.Connection.connectionString:

```
"Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};Dbq=\\folder1\folder2\User1\Database.mdb; Uid=Admin;Pwd=password;"
```

The connection via this connectionString works fine I think, I don't get any error-messages when connecting to the DB.

I checked that CurrentProject.Connection is really the connection I need.

I don't understand why my Application can't find this stored procedure although it is stored on the server.

Thanks for reading

Comment: Have you tried removing the [dbo].  from CommandText ?

Comment: Yeah, then I get the message that "[storedProcedureName]" can't be found.

Comment: StoredProcedures in Access??

Comment: The storedProcedures are stored on an external server and I want to use them in Access2010. Before the upgrade to Access2010 my colleagues were used to create the command object for the stored procedure this way: Dim qdfWork As QueryDef ... Set qdfWork = conWork.CreateQueryDef("", "{call dbo.storedProcedureName(?)}"). Now I've to make it work in Access2010. Therefore I'm using ADODB. I'm not experienced in Access at all..don't know what you mean by asking "SP in Access??" ...I don't know what type of server this is but my connectionString can successfully connect to it.

Comment: or at least I don't receive any Errors when connecting to the database

Comment: `The storedProcedures are stored on an external server` - **Where** exactly are they stored? In the .mdb? That I doubt. I have never seen SPs in Access (at least not in .mdb databases) - except when it is a Access *project* with a linked SQL Server database. Is that so? I assume you will have to connect to the linked SQL Server directly to execute SPs like this. Please anybody correct me if I'm wrong here.

Comment: The stored procedure resides on a SQL Server database (dbo is the default schema in SQL Server). You will need to create a new connection to the SQL Server. You will not be able to use the one pointing to an mdb. It may be helpful for you to provide more facts concerning the 2003 version that worked rather than the 2010 which is broken.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the comments! The stored procedure was stored on an external SQL Server. I can successfully establish the connection to the SQL Server and run the application (incl. the stored procedure). I have one (little) "problem": My connection string to the SQL Server looks like this: conWork.ConnectionString = "ODBC;DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=mySqlServer.xy.yz;DATABASE=dbName;DSN=dbName-p;UID=dbUser;PWD=dbPwd;APP=Microsoft® Access;Network=DBMSSOCN;Address=mySqlServer.xy.yz".

Comment: My problem: Every first time after opening the MS-Access-2010 file when I want to run my Access application an SQL Server Login window pops up and prompts me to enter the PWD "dbPwd" (same as from connectionString) for the user dbUser (same as from connectionString). Afterwards, when running the application for another time, I don't have to enter the pw again. I have to enter the pw only if I close MS-Access and open it again.

Comment: Dou you need Access *at all*? Why not work directly with the SQL Server?

Comment: Yes, I need Access. This application is pretty big and important and a lot of people are working with it in Access... my task is to change a particular source code to make it run in MSAccess2010.